# Import nested MongoDB to Pandas

Tags: python, json, mongodb, pandas

I have a Collection with heavily nested docs in MongoDB, I want to flatten and import to Pandas. There are some nested dicts, but also a list of dicts that I want to transform into columns (see examples below for details).

I already have function, that works for smaller batches of documents. But the solution (I found it [in the answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347906/getting-nested-data-from-mongodb-into-a-pandas-data-frame)) uses json. The problem with the `json.loads` operation is, that it fails with a `MemoryError` on bigger selections from the Collection.

I tried many solutions suggesting other json-parsers (e.g. ijson), but for different reasons none of them solved my problem. The only way left, if I want to keep up the transformation via json, would be chunking bigger selections into smaller groups of documents and iterate the parsing.

At this point I thought, - and that is my main question here - maybe there is a smarter way to do the unnesting without taking the detour through json directly in MongoDB or in Pandas or somehow combined?

This is a shortened example Doc:

```
{
  '_id': ObjectId('5b40fcc4affb061b8871cbc5'),
  'eventId': 2,
  'sId' : 6833,
  'stage': {
    'value': 1,
    'Name': 'FirstStage'
  },
  'quality': [
    {
      'type': {
        'value': 2,
        'Name': 'Color'
      },
      'value': '124'
    },
    {
      'type': {
        'value': 7,
        'Name': 'Length'
      },
      'value': 'Short'
    },
    {
      'type': {
        'value': 15,
        'Name': 'Printed'
      }
    }
}
```

This is what a succcesful dataframe-representation would look like (I skipped columns '_id' and 'sId' for readability:

```
    eventId    stage.value    stage.name    q_color    q_length    q_printed
1   2          1              'FirstStage'  124        'Short'     1
```

My code so far (which runs into memory problems - see above):

```
def load_events(filter = 'sId', id = 6833, all = False):
  if all:
    print('Loading all events.')
    cursor = events.find()
  else:
    print('Loading events with %s equal to %s.' %(filter, id))
    print('Filtering...')
    cursor = events.find({filter : id})

  print('Loading...')
  l = list(cursor)

  print('Parsing json...')
  sanitized = json.loads(json_util.dumps(l))

  print('Parsing quality...')
  for ev in sanitized:
    for q in ev['quality']:
        name = 'q_' + str(q['type']['Name'])
        value = q.pop('value', 1)
        ev[name] = value
    ev.pop('quality',None)

  normalized = json_normalize(sanitized)

  df = pd.DataFrame(normalized)

  return df
```

Comment: The variable `events` is not defined

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to convert the nested structures using json parsers. Just create your dataframe from the record list:

```
df = DataFrame(list(cursor))
```

and afterwards use pandas in order to unpack your lists and dictionaries:

```
import pandas
from itertools import chain
import numpy

df = pandas.DataFrame(t)
df['stage.value'] = df['stage'].apply(lambda cell: cell['value'])
df['stage.name'] = df['stage'].apply(lambda cell: cell['Name'])
df['q_']= df['quality'].apply(lambda cell: [(m['type']['Name'], m['value'] if 'value' in m.keys() else 1) for m in cell])
df['q_'] = df['q_'].apply(lambda cell: dict((k, v) for k, v in cell))
keys = set(chain(*df['q_'].apply(lambda column: column.keys())))
for key in keys:
    column_name = 'q_{}'.format(key).lower()
    df[column_name] = df['q_'].apply(lambda cell: cell[key] if key in cell.keys() else numpy.NaN) 
df.drop(['stage', 'quality', 'q_'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

I use three steps in order to unpack the nested data types. Firstly, the names and values are used to create a flat list of pairs (tuples). In the second step a dictionary based on the tuples takes keys from 1st and values from 2nd location of the tuples. Then all existing property names are extracted once using a set. Each property gets a new column using a loop. Inside the loop the values of each pair is mapped to the respective column cells.

Comment: Thank you, that is more or less what I was looking for. One problem remains, which was not visible in the data as it was displayed above. There are a lot of possible entries under quality (about 100). The documents always only have a small selection of 0-10 of them. If the q_ is not in the document there should be a NaN in the respecting field of the respecting column.  
So 1) I wonder, if your solution would throw a KeyError?
2) I could hard-code every one of them, bit that seems to be a lot of work and not very elegant.

Comment: PS: As this seems to be a completely new angle I'll open up a follow up question and marked your answer as accepted. Thank you!

Comment: I updated my answer. Now it should better fit your needs. Maybe it is faster to use a Pymongo query in order to filter all keys.

Comment: Oh yes, it works, thank you so much! I also tried the Pymongo query, it was much slower than your 'chain magic'. ;-)

Comment: The variable `t` is not defined