# Getting Data as String From Embedded Mongo Document

Tags: mongodb, pandas, pymongo

I am using pymongo to import data from Mongo DB. But I have embedded document in mongo DB. I am using following method to get embedded documents as string.

> From This Link:
>   [Getting nested data from MongoDB into a Pandas data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347906/getting-nested-data-from-mongodb-into-a-pandas-data-frame)

```
import pandas as pd
from bson import json_util, ObjectId
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import json

def mongo_to_dataframe(mongo_data):

        sanitized = json.loads(json_util.dumps(mongo_data))
        normalized = json_normalize(sanitized)
        df = pd.DataFrame(normalized)

        return df
```

Dataset I get after using this method:

[image: Raw data from mongo_to_dataframe method]

So now I want to remove Object type from embedded document. Suppose from order_history data showing as follows:

[image: order_history column data]

I want to remove '$uuid' or '$date' key from this dataset and want to show as plain string.

Comment: please share expected output format.

Comment: Expected format is like: 

[{'order_id': 'erfwsfksmfksm3534rt46hd4d3f63d3fd', 'applied_on': '1514879356845'}, {'order_id': 'dth4n69dh37fhrgn529fgnvs58tnbf9n49', 'applied_on': '1514879356838'}, {'order_id': 'ch638fnbsdgf538cnw638cbdf39dhde87', 'applied_on': '15148793568362'}]