# How to Flatten dataframe having ObjectID and Datetime value in column

Tags: python, pandas, python-datetime, objectid

I have one dataframe DF Columns as below

[image: Having Column1]

How can I flatten Columns values into two different column containing objectID and datetime seperate values

I tried but flat_table not working  on this column

Comment: Is possible use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33347906/getting-nested-data-from-mongodb-into-a-pandas-data-frame) solution?

Answer (score 0):

Assume the empty rows in your pic are `''` and other rows are already list type.

```py
dummy = dict.fromkeys({'pid': '', 'pts': 1, 'eo': ''}, '')

flatten = [l[0] if l != '' else dummy for l in df['DF'].tolist()]

df_ = pd.DataFrame(flatten)
```

```
# print(df_)

    pid pts     eo
0  pid1   0  date1
1                 
2  pid2   1  date2
3                 
4  pid3   0  date2
```